# Laravel - Declaration of Illuminate\Support\Carbon::__set_state(array $array) should be compatible with Carbon\Carbon::__set_state($state)

Tags: php, laravel

Got this weird error while trying to use laravel for the first time, look it up but couldn't find anything, could someone please help?

[image: Screen shot of the error]

Comment: Looks like a library mismatch, how did you install Laravel? Is this out of the box or? For downvotes - don't, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has a class that extends the official Carbon class. Carbon had changed their `__set_state` method signature, which broke Laravel's Carbon implementation. After Laravel fixed it and made a release, Carbon reverted their change to `__set_state`, which re-broke Laravel's implementation.

Basically, this is a temporary problem, and running `composer update` later should fix your issue.

Related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23458
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23465

Answer (score 2):

The problem is already fixed: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23464